# Characteristic function vs Moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

Normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2$) has the moment generating function $$m_X(t) = \exp (\mu t+\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2})$$ and the characteristic function $$\phi_X(t) = \exp (i \mu t-\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2})$$ which looks almost the same. In fact, it satisfies the equation $$m_X(it) = \phi_X(t)$$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My question** : Is there a criterion for a distribution to satisfy $m_X(it) = \phi_X(t)$ ? I'm especially interested in continuous distributions.

I had a course on measure theory, and I'm new to probability theory. I know that moment generating function can be failed to be defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. I saw some examples of moment generating functions and characteristic functions, and all of them satisfy the equation above.

Comment: Not all random variables have moment generating functions. But if the MGF of a continuous random variable exists, it satisfies your given criterion, i.e., $m_X(it) = \phi_X(t)$.

Comment: See also e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419045/is-it-always-possible-to-convert-a-moment-generating-function-into-a-characteris?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it always possible to convert a Moment Generating Function into a Characteristic Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419045/is-it-always-possible-to-convert-a-moment-generating-function-into-a-characteris)

Comment: @delivery101 's comment is correct but has the unneeded qualification that the rv in question is continuous.  In general, if the mgf exists, the formula relating it to the characteristic function is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Would it be possible to give me a proof or a reference?